# You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have upgraded react-router-dom to v6 from v5. Previously(v5) it used to work well.
Here is the code.

```
<HashRouter>
    <Provider appStore={appStore}>
        <MemoryRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route/>
            </Routes>
        </MemoryRouter>
    </Provider>
</HashRouter>
```

Comment: The link you shared is not 'answered'. Not sure which is the right solution.

Comment: Is the error message not clear? You are rendering a router within another router. There only needs to be one single router to provide a routing context for the entire app. Remove one or the other of the `HashRouter` or `MemoryRouter`.

Answer (score 2):

you actually do have a Router inside a Router remove either the memory router or hash Router and it should work fine

```
<Provider appStore={appStore}>
    <MemoryRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route/>
        </Routes>
    </MemoryRouter>
</Provider>
```

it should work like this or remove memory router if you want I searched online and got same answers Hope i was able to help

Comment: Thank you. I guess i should have been more clear. 
In my case this part is coming from a different package. Not sure what other options i have.

<MemoryRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route/>
            </Routes>
</MemoryRouter>